# How to see foreign reviews to your app on App Store?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, review

How can i see, on my Mac or iPhone, the reviews from other Stores to the apps i posted on the AppStore?I only see the ones from my country.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question about Apple policies and processes, and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Sorry if i posted in the wrong section!Anyway i was searching for a program(osx)/spp(iPhone) able to do that as long as i don't think there is a proper way via the app manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your app in iTunes connect, select "Manage Your Apps", then select the app you want to see the review of. Next just select "Customer Reviews" and just like below, there will be a spot to change the country of the review.

[image]

Comment: I did but i'm only available to choose my own country! Was wondering if there was any program/app to see that.

Comment: That must mean there are no reviews in other countries

Comment: I don't know how to do it in the new iTunes Connect, but AppAnnie aggregates and displays all of them.  Search for your app on appannie.com.